# What are the most commonly used Java Frameworks?

Tags: java, frameworks

for me I will answer this question based on my experience.

**so if I'm gonna start new project I will use the following technologies:**

1. [AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/) as [MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture) framework.
2. Spring (DI, Interceptors, Quartz, ACEGI, ... etc).
3. Hibernate.
4. JSF.

**off course you might need to play with some helper frameworks/libraries such as:**

1. Velocity.
2. CAS; if you need SSO.
3. JXLs; if you need small and easy library for generating Excel files using XLS templates.
4. Drools; which is Artificial Intelligence a Rule Engine that uses the Rule Based approached to implement an Expert System and is more correctly classified as a Production Rule System.

**in terms of testing I will consider the following frameworks:**

1. TestNG; you may want to use JUnit in the part of Unit Testing but TestNG is more than a unite testing framework;
2. WATIR or SELENIUM as web testing;

Can anybody else suggest other options?

Comment: what do you mean with Last published?
in the main page there is news posted that AndroMDA 3.3 Final is released and available for download! Monday, 21 April 2008

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are just a few answers to your question that can be found on StackOverflow.

- [Best Java framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257712/)
- [What is the most commonly used Java web framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742223/)
- [Best java mvc framework implementation for web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309254/)
- [What are the best MVC web frameworks on the market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450/)
- [What are the best Java social networking frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283922/)
- [Best server-side framework for heavy AJAX Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736/)
- [What Web Application Framework for Java is Recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596/)
- [Java Validation Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397852/)
- [Validation Framework in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580686/)
- [Java 2D Game Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/)
- [What are good docking frameworks for Java/Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304874/)
- [Which framework should I choose - Seam, Wicket, JSF or GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745029/)
- [Java Frameworks War: Spring and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100243/)
- [Recommended framework for Java Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289977/)
- [Java Desktop application framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002/)
- [Alternate Java GUI Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286251/)
- [What’s the best mock framework for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/)
- [Java configuration framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765/)

You can do this search yourself via [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+framework&hl=en)

Comment: In fact, the question is the answer in the second thread of your given list. :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure, what I am gonna use in the coming new project. Unless otherwise, I am planning to do [RDD](http://shahid.shah.org/index.php/archives/15), also [here](http://willcode4beer.com/opinion.jsp?set=in_favor_of_rdd) and [here](http://www.thousandtyone.com/blog/ResumeDrivenDevelopmentTheHammerAndTheNail.aspx).

Comment: I like RDD this is the first time I read about RDD, its real and funny

For me I may not be able to pass interview in any of the frameworks listed above; I believe that the interview should be about your ability to find solutions, not about your frameworks knowledge;

Comment: And I agree with this believe of yours. :)

Comment: I was once asked if i had some experiance with WebLogic7(yes, not only specific app server, but also specific version). RDD rules and deep down inside you know it. we all know that all app servers are the same, but .. now ive experiance with almost all of them.

Comment: heheheheh, you will find this normal if you know that I was once asked if I know what functions specific class contains, and what are the parameters for those methods. most people can't believe that a few minutes of googling can answer this questions; unless they don't have internet connection ;)

Answer (score 2):

thanks Eddie for Googling hint.

When I asked this question I was biased to Web Application Development. Now I found this can't be answered in single question.
So I guess its better to have one page categorizing the Java Frameworks (DI, Web, ORM) with links in each category pointing to other questions in stackoverflow.

however this may end with something similar to [java-source.net](http://java-source.net/)
  but categorized. so I will use your hint Eddie in my answer below:

**[ORM (Object Relational Mapping)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) frameworks:**

- [Hibernate, iBatis, Java EE or other Java ORM tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716532/hibernate-ibatis-jee-or-other-java-orm-tool)
- [What Java ORM do you prefer, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why)

**[DI / IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) frameworks:**

- [What DI/IoC framework should I learn next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582098/what-di-ioc-framework-should-i-learn-next)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71041/which-single-ioc-di-container-would-you-recommend-using-and-why

**Web frameworks:**

- [What is the best java web application framework that goes well with xml+xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671297/what-is-the-best-java-web-application-framework-that-goes-well-with-xmlxslt)
- [Which Java Web Framework fits best with Google Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481705/which-java-web-framework-fits-best-with-google-guice)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309254/best-java-mvc-framework-implementation-for-web-apps
- [Which Java web framework best accommodates web designers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508225/what-java-web-framework-best-accomodates-web-ui-designers)

**Report engines:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238527/what-is-the-best-report-engine-for-java
- [What is the best free or low-cost Java reporting library (e.g. BIRT, JasperReports, etc.) for making newspaper-like reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708588/what-is-the-best-free-or-low-cost-java-reporting-library-e-g-birt-jasperreport)

**Testing Frameworks:**

- [Which is the best tool for automatic GUI performance testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92679/which-is-the-best-tool-for-automatic-gui-performance-testing)
- [What's the best mock framework for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/whats-the-best-mock-framework-for-java)
- [What's the best mock framework for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697/)

**GUI libraries:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138722/which-gui-library-is-the-best-in-java

**[Code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) tools:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329/what-is-your-favourite-code-coverage-tools-free-and-non-free

**[Build tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation):**

- [What Tools Do You Recommend To Auto-Build Your Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191093/what-tools-do-you-recommend-to-auto-build-your-application/191147)
- [Available Build Tools (make, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247350/available-build-tools-make-etc)

**Static analysis tools:**

- [What code metric(s) convince you that provided code is "crappy"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187289/what-code-metrics-convince-you-that-provided-code-is-crappy/187330#187330)
- [Find bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

*if I missed something please let me know to update this answer. (thanks all)*

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget some [static analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187289/what-code-metrics-convince-you-that-provided-code-is-crappy/187330#187330) tools, like for instance [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Frameworks are means to an end. What is the project that you are trying to accomplish?
Tons of people use Spring, but for some people some obscure open-source API may save years of coding.

Answer (score 1):

Before you grab the latest and greatest or not - perhaps you should note what you actually need and then find the best match ratehr than just grabbing jar files.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but there are some minimum frameworks that will be used, for example if you will interact with database one of ORM frameworks should be considered, also I see one of DI frameworks should be of your choice in any real application; and this is what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I would also use these tools to build the project and follow the rules.

Maven build system

Nexus repository server

Hudson CI server

PMD, FindBugs

Checkstyle

Jalopy